# check whether div element is visible on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do animate image on div load event only but image get animated on page load. So to do it I check for div visible plugin. I am using [Visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) plugin to check whether content is visible on screen or not. This works fine if I do it in separate file but if I integrate in my actual website it won't work at all. I am really not getting why it is not working after integrating in my website. Please help me.

```
if($('#slide1').visible(true))
          alert('visible');
```

html code:

```
<div id="silde1"> <img src="sample.png" /> </div>
```

This code works if I do it in separate file. But not in my website.

Comment: Add few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plugin for something so simple... why don't you just do something like -

```
if($("#element").css("display") == "none") { .. }
```

or

```
if($("#element").css("visibility") == "hidden") { .. }
```

depending upon what you mean by visibility.

Comment: visible means display on view port.

Comment: You mean like elements with anything other than display:none right?

Comment: yes. All elements get active on page load but when we scroll down they display on viewport that event I want